# Update certain columns in sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I have an update query like this:

```
update
set
column1 = @col1,
column2 = @col2,
...
column10 = @col10
from table
where table.id=@col0
```

I only need to update certain columns depends on user's input. How do I skip certain columns when passing the values into this query?

Comment: Do you mean conditionally skip certain columns? Like if you have `@col1` and `@col3` values, the update will only update those two columns? Is this in a stored procedure or in C# directly - meaning, where/how does this query get generated and run? These factors will determine the answers.

Comment: Yes conditionally skip certain columns. This is using in C# directly but it's in a resource file. I can't use c# to conditionally concatenate sql string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use case in the update statement.
Hope this helps:

Let's assume your table is as below:

```
create table tblTest
(
  ID int,
  column1 varchar(10),
  column2 varchar(10),
  column3 varchar(10),
  column4 varchar(10),
  column5 varchar(10)
)
```

Insert values for test:

```
Insert into tblTest (ID, Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4, Column5) values (1,'a','b','c','d','e')
```

Set up variables for test.

```
  declare @ID int
  declare @col1 varchar(10)
  declare @col2 varchar(10)
  declare @col3 varchar(10)
  declare @col4 varchar(10)
  declare @col5 varchar(10)

  set @ID = 1
  set @col1 = 'a'
  set @col2 = ''
  set @col3 = 'y'
  set @col4 = 'd'
  set @col5 = 'z'

  update tblTest 
    set 
        column1 = case when LEN(@col1) > 0 then @col1 else column1 end,
        column2 = case when LEN(@col2) > 0 then @col2 else column2 end ,
        column3 = case when LEN(@col3) > 0 then @col3 else column3 end ,
        column4 = case when LEN(@col4) > 0 then @col4 else column4 end ,
        column5 = case when LEN(@col5) > 0 then @col5 else column5 end 
    where
        ID = @ID



select * from tblTest
```

I've created a sample in SQL Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e666d/6

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you can either send them as case statements so if you are passing @col1 as NULL or '' then you can do

```
update
set
column1 = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@col1,'')='' THEN column1 ELSE @col1 END,,
column2 = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@col2,'')='' THEN column2 ELSE @col2 END,,
...
column10 = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@col10,'')='' THEN column10 ELSE @col10 END,
from table
where table.id=@col0
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `IsNull()` for it:

```
update
set
column1 = IsNull(@col1,column1),
column2 = IsNull(@col2,column2),
...
column10 = IsNull(@col10,column10)
from table
where table.id=@col0
```

what it would to, it would check if the variable (`@col1`, `@col2` etc) is `NULL` and if so, update the column to its current value, otherwise update to variable's value. It'll work as long as missing variables are nulls